# End-to-end testing from desktop app to website

Tags: automated-testing, test-management, test-automation-framework, qa-developer, protractor

I'm currently investigating ways for executing End-to-end testing on a system that contains two parts which are dependent on one another. The first part is a desktop application and the second is a web interface. The desktop application runs on Windows 7 and the Web interface has to work with IE9, IE10 and IE11.

The desktop application uses an API which allows the web interface to retrieve data stored in the desktop application. Data is always retrieved when the web interface is first open and is also retrieved when you click refresh in the web interface. This allows for editing in the desktop application without needing to write it back from the web interface to the desktop application.

Currently I have End-to-end tests on the web interface side using Protractor, which is working fine. I want my test coverage to include my application. I have looked into Telerik Test Studio, but my desktop application isn't WPF so it won't work.

Does anyone have any ideas for possible solutions?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SQA! Could you add some details like the OS the desktop application is running on? Such detail would help answering your question.

Comment: Is it MFC or WinFroms or any other kind of app?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you not to bind any particular automation tools to your testing. Which means that at the test framework level, you need to have a shared layer as the interface to the test automation developers. While underline framework development could use any automation tool which works fine with different kinds of applications like web and win form. In this case your needs (automation test) and the tools you use (the particular technologies the SUT uses) are separated. That enables you to leverage what ever automation tools works with your SUT. For example, you may use LDTP, or Sikuli or QuickTest to drive your desktop SUT at the sametime. Or replace on with another, but the modification required to your test cases are minimal, even transparent.

Back to your question, which automation tool works better with your winform SUT depends on what kind of technology is used to build the winform. If it is MFC or WPF, I think tools like QuickTest or WinLDTP could be the options, if it is Java Swing, there is special test tool to do that. Also you need to consider if you would only use opensource or free tools, or you have budget for commercial automation tools.

Answer (score 0):

You could use NUnit (or something similar), combined with C# (Again, or something similar) - with the nuGet Test Stack for accessing the application and Selenium to access the web interface.

Not having all of your specifics, I can't give a much more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I use WinTask, which can automate both desktop and web applications. One script can handle both.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to automate tests for web and desktop applications you could use CodedUI tests. 
The tests can be made in Microsoft Test Manager. 
The CodedUI tests can then optionally be made more generic, so it is better maintainable and extendable.